# Why would different Shuttle orbits have different mission directors?

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle

The Wikipedia page for NASA Flight director [Holly Ridings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holly_Ridings) contains a portrait with two other STS-117 mission flight directors. The caption there says:

> Flight directors for the STS-117 mission in June 2007. Annette Hasbrook (ISS Orbit 1), Kelly Beck (ISS Orbit 2 & lead) and Holly Ridings (ISS Orbit 3).

**Question:** Why would different Shuttle orbits have different mission directors?

[image]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nasa_Flight_Directors_in_2007_inc_Holly_Ridings.jpg)

Comment: The “1” goes with Team, not with Orbit. I.e “ISS-on-Orbit team #1”, team #2, etc.

Comment: Unlike machines, people need to sleep, and temporarily get their minds off the job. We humans don't function well 24/7/365. The Shuttle, on the other hand, did orbit 24/7.

Comment: @DavidHammen I thought that 93 minutes was a bit fast for a sleep-wake cycle; now I see that "orbit" is figurative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are shift/team names. There was an Ascent/Entry Team, a Planning Shift, and two Orbit teams to provide 24/7 coverage in MCC during shuttle missions. (One of the Orbit teams was Planning shift for shuttle - don't know about ISS)

I suppose for ISS flight control it's just Orbit (shift) 1, 2, and 3 for 24/7 coverage.

Here's a snippet of a Space Shuttle mission flight control team shift schedule, showing the rotation of the teams. (This launch attempt ended up being scrubbed)

[image]

Source: personal notes